# show/hide header footer when scroll to/from a div bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I need to hide the header and show the footer (and vice-versa)
when I scroll down (reaching the bottom) and I scroll up (leaving the bottom) a certain `<div>`:

I am using jQuery, and at the moment I have a bug in my code that is driving me crazy:
after scroll everything starts "bouncing" repeatedly...

I tried to use `stop()`, `one()`, `queue: false`, but with no success...

The problem seems to come when I set the height of `#main`,
(and seems to work fine if that part is commented out, like in the code below)

But I need to resize `#main` because the footer is bigger than the header.

```
$(window).load(function(){

xxx = '';
$main.css('height','calc(100% - 79px)');

$('.column.right').on('scroll', function(){

    if( ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()) == $(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        xxx = 'equal';
        console.log('equal');

        $header.one().stop().slideUp();
        $footer.one().stop().slideDown({ queue: false, duration: 100, complete: function(){ setTimeout(function(){ /*$main.css('height','calc(100% - 221px)');*/ }, 0); } });
    }
    else if( ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()) < ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - 0) && xxx == 'equal'){
        xxx = 'minor';
        console.log('minor');

        $header.one().stop().slideDown();
        $footer.one().stop().slideUp({ queue: false, duration: 100, complete: function(){ setTimeout(function(){ /*$main.css('height','calc(100% - 79px)');*/ }, 0); } });  
    }

});

});
```

I am using also CSS `overflow: hidden` on `html` and `body`

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/
this is what i think you are asking for ..just check this out.  i am sure this will help you
html code-

```
<header class="nav-down">
    This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
    This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
    This is your footer.
</footer>
```

javascript code-

```
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

css code-

```
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}

main {
   background:url(
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
   ) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}

footer { background: #ddd;}
* { color: transparent}
```

Comment: Seems that it shows/hides basing on the mouse wheel acceleration, I need to use a div "scroll-to/from-bottom" point instead